# how to control api_key in Laravel API route

Tags: php, laravel, api

I write an API using Laravel, I want to define an `api_key` like this link

> `http://example.com/api/USER_API_KEY/json/method`

this `API_KEY` defines that the user has an access to the API or not. To implement this issue, I have to check the database to see what's going on.

How can I implement this in my `api.php` route

**api.php**

```
Route::prefix('json')->group(function () {
    Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/', function () {
        return response('No functionality found', 200)
            ->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    });

    Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/SingleSend', 'ApiControlller@SingleSend');
});
```

Comment: no you do not want to do that logic in api.php. Create a middleware for that and grab $request->segment() parse it and check the token if user has the rights to access the app.  Onion:  Request-> Middleware ->Middleware->Controller->Response

Comment: @LeoinstanceofKelmendi Sorry, Could you write this in short answer? I will be so thankful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a middleware by running the command in console:

```
php artisan make:middleware <MiddlewareName>
```

This command creates your middleware class in `app/Http/Middleware`

Open middleware class and add the logic to the middleware to verify user token.

You will have a method `handle()` defined on middleware there you want to check if token is valid or not.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)
{
   $apiToken = $request->get('token', null);

   //here you can get user token from database and compare with the apiToken

   if(empty($apiToken)){

        return response('forbbiden', 403);
    }
   return $next($request);
}
```

If you want a middleware to run on every request, go to `app/Http/kernel.php` under `$routeMiddleware` and add your middleware.

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...
    'verify-api-token' => \App\Http\Middleware\YourMiddlwareName::class,
    ...
];
```

Attaching your middleware to the route:

```
Route::prefix('json')->group(['middleware' => 'verify-api-token'], function () {
    Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/', function () {
        return response('No functionality found', 200)
            ->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    });

    Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/SingleSend', 'ApiControlller@SingleSend');
});
```